# SQL Azure reliability and scalability

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I need to make sure the availability  of my database is high. working with SQL Azure does not make that clear.
Is there a way to run multi servers (one will take over if one server fails? ) under SQL Azure, above that is there something equivalent to  increasing memory on the DB server to speed up the Database processing ?

Answer (score 2):

Read High Availability on the [Intro the Azure SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336230.aspx) and then read [Business Continuity in Windows Azure SQL Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh852669.aspx).  To summarize:

> Data durability and fault tolerance is enhanced by maintaining
>   multiple copies of all data in different physical nodes located across
>   fully independent physical sub-systems such as server racks and
>   network routers. At any one time, Windows Azure SQL Database keeps
>   three replicas of data running—one primary replica and two secondary
>   replicas.

Answer (score 1):

Right now there is no way to specify hardware configuration for SQL Azure Databases. It's totally out of your control and from SAAS perspective that makes sense. The backend management services are responsible making sure you get the best performance possible.

If you need dedicated and reserved hardware for your SQL deployment you may take a look at IAAS offerings in Azure and start a VM with SQL installed however you need to make sure you know the main differences between a IAAS and PAAS offering.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what your high availability requirements are, but you should look at the [SLAs](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/) provided by Microsoft. SQL Database offers 99.9% monthly availability.